# Stuck on a possibly impossible discrete mathematics question.

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I have a question, I have received some homework with a question on it that I either don't understand or is literally impossible.
 The question is
Consider $f: \Bbb{N} \to\Bbb{N}:$ given by $f(n) = 5n+1.$ Find the image of $A = \{2,3,5,7,11\}.$

Isn't this question impossible because there are no natural numbers that can be multiplied by 5 to get a value less than 5? Or am I misinterpreting the question. If so, how would one solve a question like this.

Comment: You should read again what the image of a set is.

Comment: I've read and re-read the definition for about an hour now, but to me it just looks what was given to me was the image, which is strange because the question asked me to find the image.

Comment: To find the image of $A$ under $f$, just apply $f$ to each element of $A$. That is, $f(A)=\{f(x) : x \in A\}$

Comment: For example, the image of $2$ would be $f(2) = 11$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The image of a set given a function $f$ is, essentially, the set of outputs $f$ generates from that set. For example:

- The image of the set $\Bbb Z$ under $f(x) = x^2$ is the set of perfect squares, $\{0,1,4,9,\cdots\}$.
- The image of the set $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$ under $f(x) = x-10$ is $\{-9,-8,-7,-6,-5\}$.
- The image of the set $\{1,2,\cdots,100\}$ under $f(x) = 1/x$ is the set $\{1,1/2,1/3,\cdots,1/100\}$.

So what you're going to need to do is take each $a \in A$, and find $f(a)$. List all of the unique $f(a)$ as a set. For instance, $f(2)=11$ in your example, so your image should include $11$.

Comment: On my work I figgured that, that was that that had meant: and had this as the solution

f(.2) = 2 
f(.4) = 3
f(.8) = 5
f(1.2) = 7
f(2) = 11

however, then I noticed that the intervals are all natural numbers, what gives with that part? (Additionally obviously all the outputs are primes)

Comment: @barronvonburp You should read this answer again (and again) until you see that it's completely different from what you described in your comment.

Comment: I genuinely don't understand this concept from the bottom of my heart, and re-reading it isn't going to help simplify it for me.